# Side effecting function returning disjunction

Tags: scala

I have a side effecting function which mutates class variable or Throw an exception if precondition isn't met. After adding into class level mutable Map I want to return a "boolean" from the function indicating a success. So below is what I am thinking about but hard-coding boolean to "true" feels inappropriate however that would be the case when it goes into yield block as otherwise left side of disjunction will be populated with an exception.

```
def add(e: Entity, value: String): \/[Throwable,Boolean] = {
checkIfFieldIsKey(e.id) match {
  case Some(id) =>
    val validId = validateIdType(..)
    for {
      k <- validId
    } yield { keys += (e -> k); true }
  case None =>
    for {
      r <- validateTypeAndValue(e, value)
    } yield { values += (e -> value); true } 
  }
}
```

where 'keys' and 'values' are 'val' instances of ConcurrentHashMap. So every time 'add' is successful right side of disjunction will always be "true" meaning boolean value will **never** be false. does this look appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a side-effecting method has no meaningful return value, you typically return `Unit`. If you want to capture the possibility of failure, it's perfectly reasonable to return `Throwable \/ Unit`, which is probably what I'd do here. In any case I'd say your intuition that it's a bad idea to return a `Throwable \/ Boolean` where the right side can never be anything but `true` is spot on.

Answer (score 1):

It seems silly. It could be reduced to `Option[Throwable]` -- `None` if successful, or the exception if it wasn't. The only thing against it is that `None` isn't usually associated with success.

As an alternative, write your own maybe monad, with `Success` and `Failure(throwable)` as it's cases.

Comment: If you're designing an API that consistently uses `Throwable \/ A` to represent the possibility of failure, I'd say that using `Throwable \/ Unit` here instead of `Option[Throwable]` isn't silly at all (even though they're of course isomorphic).

Comment: @TravisBrown Excellent point. It did not occur to me to use `\/ Unit`, though I'd still prefer a custom monad if the code does not follow the path of other `\/` usages.